# Can't freeze camera on spot during animation

Tags: animation

I have a camera tha'ts following a bezier curve, but at some point I want it to stop. So far I tried setting the keyframe to the offset position, but it either just continues or does some backward-forward animation.

I tried duplicating the camera and setting a keframe at the position/rotation etc, but once I delete the follow-path of the duplicated camera, it resets to another view and ignores any location keyframe info it seems.

I also tried the 'stored views' plugin, to manually set the camera view to a new camera, but the options are grey..it only works for user-defined views, and not the camera.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to simply duplicate the keyframe, if it still doesn't work please share your file (only camera + curve) and tell at what frame it is supposed to freeze: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks @moonboots, duplicating the frame didnt work for me, you can check the file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/65645fb3ad724495971b32e46cc1bdd7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've pressed on the *Animate Path* button of the *Follow Path* constraint, you should have not, it has created a *Generator* modifier for the curve, which makes the camera move automatically along the curve and add an animation to the one you try to create.

What you need to do is select the curve, switch a window to *Graph Editor*, select the *Evaluation Time* track, open the *N panel > Modifiers* and remove the *Generator*. Now only the *Offset* keyframe you'll create will be taken into account for the camera movement.

[image]

Or you can use the Marty Fouts' suggestion, which is deleting the *Generator* and keyframe the *Evaluation Time* in *Object Data panel > Path Animation > Evaluation Time*. In that case, for the camera itself, you don't need to keyframe its *Offset*, only its rotations:

[image]

Comment: Nice catch.  I usually don't miss it when they've done that.

Comment: Yes a bit confusing. About your previous question: you need to make sure that you've selected the Evaluation Time track. The object won't move by itselft unless you've clicked on Animated Path, in that case it creates the Generator modifier + you can keyframe the curve's Animation Path

Comment: I know.  I realized that right after I posted the question.  That's why I deleted it so quickly.

Comment: You don't need to click on animated path.  The curve has path animation enabled by default.  You only need to set keyframes on the curve's evaluation time.   If you do it that way no generator is created.  That's part of why using evaluation time is preferred.

Comment: oh ok I didn't know that

Comment: Yes, removing the generator worked!

Answer (score 3):

Follow Path animation can be confusing because you usually do not want to animate the offset of the object following the path; but rather the evaluation time of the path.  To fix your animation

1. Delete the animation of Object Offset
2. Go to the curve.

- At frame 1 set the Evaluation Time to -1 and make a keyframe.
- At the time you want the animation to stop (frame 180?) set the Evaluation time to 100 and make a keyframe.

You may have to adjust the location of your camera rotation keyframes to match.

EDIT:  To clarify

Path animation using *follow path* modifier can be done in two different ways.  If you select *Animate Path* on the modifier it creates an animation on the curve, as Moonboots described in [their answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258937/42221) above.  As they pointed out and I neglected to mention, that adds a generator to the animation, causing it be be extrapolated indefinitely into the future.

This is why they deserve to have their answer accepted, and why your camera continued to travel past the end of the curve.  If you had chosen a closed curve, then the camera would simply follow the path over again.

What I suggested is the more common way to animate a Follow Path because it gives you more control over the animation.

[Path animation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/path_animation.html) is a bit confusing, and the way it works changed between blender 2.8 and 2.9, but this is how it works in recent versions of blender:

The length of the path is divided into segments, one segment for each "frame" in the Path Animation *Frames* setting.  The *Evaluation Time* is a measure of how many segments along the path the camera should be positioned.

The default value of *Frames* is 100, so you can think of *Evaluation Time* as the percentage of the path the camera has moved along.

By animating this way, you can do things like move the camera forward some ways, pause it, and move it again, either forward or backward.

Comment: do you mean "their answer" because we are two boots?   ^^

Comment: because I'm a language snob and think if singular 'they' was [good enough in 1375](https://public.oed.com/blog/a-brief-history-of-singular-they/) it's good enough now. :P

Comment: although, there being two of you would go along way towards explaining how you manage to answer so many questions so quickly. ;)

Comment: Lots of confusing settings here, but thanks both for the detailed explanations. In the end, I had to remove the generator, and set the evaluation time to zero. remove the offset keyframes and use evaluation time for keyframes.